# How many tty and pts are running on my pc?

Tags: gui, tty

I found that more pts can be created this way.

1. To reboot into text mode-tty1
2. to input `startx` to jump into gui mode.
   To enter terminal in the gui mode started from tty1 to inupt.

   ```
     tty    
     /dev/pts/0
   ```

this gui is pts/0

3. to input  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> to jump into
   another text mode-tty2
4. to input `startx` to jump into gui mode, this gui is pts/1.

To enter terminal in the gui mode started from tty2 to inupt

```
    tty
    /dev/pts/1
```

Now two gui modes can be created.
How to know how many tty and pts are running at the same time on my pc?

Every gui program--include virtual terminal in gui is the client(or say slave) of x-server(or say x window system) ,so it was called pesudo terminal slave.

Muru give me many new knowledge,maybe there is a wrong expression in muru's explaination.
[image: something about pts from other view]

In my opinion,the proper sentence would be that:
but that's an application program in X server started from the tty1, but also a pts.

Please see the discuss here on [what is pts/0 and (:0.0) in linux when typing who am i](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72177/what-is-pts-0-and-0-0-in-linux-when-typing-who-am-i)

[image: quoting from an answer]

From the knowledge,i draw my conclusion.

It not only an X server started from the tty1, but also a pts.

Comment: :"Now two gui modes can be created."  Not on Unity. The tty7 used for Unity is hardcoded in the software

Answer (score 1):

> this gui is pts/0

Um, nope. I'm not sure where you got `pts/0` from, but that's an X server started from the tty1, it isn't pts/0. See [this U&L post for more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21280/70524).

At any given time, by default, there are 6 TTYs with getty running on them (so that you can login there) - TTYs 1-6, which you can access using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>. TTY 7 has the GUI started by default. On 16.04 and above, you can start more getty instances using:

```
systemctl start getty@ttyN
```

Replacing `N` with an appropriate number.

To find the number of pseudoterminals currently open, you can do:

```
ps -eo tty= | sort -u
```

`ps -e` lists all processes, and `-o tty=` lists the process TTYs without a header line. `sort` and get unique entries with `-u`. For example:

```
$ ps -eo tty= | sort -u
?
pts/0
pts/1
pts/2
tty1
ttyS0
```

Comment: To input tty in gui terminal ,we can get output info:   
 pts/0

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Oh? Open a couple more terminals at the same time in the same GUI and check the output there too.

Comment: Every gui program--include virtual terminal in gui is the client(or say slave) of x-server(or say x window system) ,so it was called pesudo terminal slave

Comment: @it_is_a_literature that makes no sense.

Comment: It does make sense,muru.

Comment: It is a wrong sentence in your explaination.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature not in English, anyway

Comment: but that's an X server started from the tty1, it isn't pts/0.

Comment: It must be expressed as :but that's an X server started from the tty1, and it is just pts/0.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72177/what-is-pts-0-and-0-0-in-linux-when-typing-who-am-i

Comment: If you're claiming that a GUI is a pseudo terminal, I don't know what gives you that idea, but that's just nonsense

Comment: Now stop bothering me with nonsensical comments