# Display all the working terminals

Tags: command-line, tty, who

I opened 4 terminals but when check them with `who` or `w`

```
me@alpha:~$ w
 17:28:19 up  3:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.51, 0.35, 0.34
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
me :0       :0               14:20   ?xdm?   3:27   0.01s /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESS
me@alpha:~$ who
me   :0           2019-01-16 14:20 (:0)
```

It display only one termianl called ':0'

if on macos it will display

```
me at mbp in ~
$ who
me  console      2019-01-04 08:57
me  ttys000      2019-01-04 08:57
me  ttys001      2019-01-04 08:57
```

How could display all the terminal ?

Comment: amazing, yes @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: Well, very nice !  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu ! 欢迎

Comment: 谢谢， 来学习了。 论语说“學而時習之”。 學 效也， 效倣， 模倣， imitate . 習， 練習(白羽）， 幼鳥 煽動 剛剛髮育的白色的羽毛。 @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: 学习是君子之乐 :) 我没读过《论语》，只是偶尔看《周易》的卦解释，但是希望以后能学到了更多古文。这样以后看《三生三世十里桃花》会看懂更多的:)  那你也以后多模倣啊，要提升Linux水平为了写在这里的答案吧，哈哈。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to how certain terminals work. In particular, `sakura` and `gnome-terminal` (Ubuntu's default) which I have used before do not register the terminal. There is, in fact, a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1280724) for gnome-terminal, which is closed with WONTFIX status.

Finding number of open terminal sessions, therefore, should be focused on finding parent processes of shell sessions or associated `pts`/`tty` devices, as shown in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/868561/295286):

```
$ ps -eo tty= | sort -u
```

The only issue with this command is that it should display processes from all users. My personal approach would be to filter out my own processes ( i.e. terminals I opened myself ) via `-u` option and parse with `awk`:

```
#  Note that this includes tabs as well, not just open windows
$ ps -u $USER -o tty | awk 'NR>1 && $1 != "?" {a[$0]++};END{for(val in a) print val}'
```